# Как реализовать функцию в Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_a(**data text[] = '{}'**)
RETURNS **json** AS $func$
    BEGIN
    **константа qu = QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT array_to_string(data, ' OR id = ');';**
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT to_json(array_agg(array_to_json(data))) FROM ah_py WHERE **'+qu+'**;';

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`**` выделил то, что не работает, и я написал это, чтобы вы примерно поняли логику функции, т.е. должен входить массив, к примеру, `{1,2,3,4}`, и потом разбираться запросом qu и добавляться в запрос, который должен вернуться ответом функции.

Comment: @Максим Поздняков, вы уверены, что серализацию данных в json вам надо делать на уровне БД?

Comment: Так получается быстрей, но в любом случае мне уже дали совет на другом форуме как реализовать, так что вопрос не актуален

Answer (score 1):

давайте по порядку:

на вход массив:

```
    data text[] DEFAULT ARRAY[null]::text[]
```

как понимаю, вот эта часть:

```
    **константа qu = QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT array_to_string(data, ' OR id = ');';**
```

делается для того что бы попасть в условие.
но это можно сделать и без EXECUTE :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_a(
    data text[] DEFAULT ARRAY[null]::text[]
)
RETURNS json AS $BODY$
    SELECT to_json(array_agg(array_to_json(data))) as json
            FROM ah_py 
            WHERE id = ANY(data);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```